# XSD - ComplexType mixed with Content Restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I Need to validate several XML-Files with one XSD-File...
The XML-Files can occur in several forms... and I need to catch
all cases.

XML1:

```
<BusinessRule>
   ABC
</BusinessRule>
```

XML2:

```
<BusinessRule>
<Case number="1">
  <Lookup class="type">
     <LkpColumn>column1</LkpColumn>
     <LkpText>someText1</LkpText>
  </Lookup>
</Case>
<Case number="2">
  <Lookup class="type">
     <LkpColumn>column2</LkpColumn>
     <LkpText>someText2</LkpText>
  </Lookup>
</Case>
<Case number="3">
  <Lookup class="type">
     <LkpColumn>column3</LkpColumn>
     <LkpText>someText3</LkpText>
  </Lookup>
</Case>
</BusinessRule>
```

XML3:

```
<BusinessRule>
   <Lookup class="type">    
      <LkpColumn>column</LkpColumn>
      <LkpText>someText</LkpText>
   </Lookup>
</BusinessRule>
```

XML4:

```
<BusinessRule>
   <If>condition1</If>
   <Then>then_bough1</Then>
   <Else>
       <If>condition2</If>
       <Then>then_bough2</Then>
       <Else>else1</Else>
   </Else>
</BusinessRule>
```

MY XSD:

```
<!-- ... -->
<!-- BusinessRule -->
<xs:complexType name="BusinessRuleType" mixed="true">
    <!-- I NEED THIS PART, BUT IT DOESN'T WORK! -->
    <!--
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent> 
    -->
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Case" type="CaseType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="Lookup" type="LookupType"/>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="If"/>
            <xs:element name="Then"/>
            <xs:element name="Else"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- case -->
<xs:complexType name="CaseType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Lookup" type="LookupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- LookUp -->
<!-- ... -->
```

I think I understood to cover XML2 - XML4...
But I also need to check the Content of XML1 with some "Restriction"-Tags...
Is this possible?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, by virtue of using `mixed="true"` your XML1 case will already be valid, but note that each of your cases will also allow the sprinkling of text between the elements of the `BusinessRule` content.  I'm guessing you probably don't want this.  If not, remove `mixed="true"` and redesign your XML1 case to use a wrapping element, say, `Symbol`:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="Symbol">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Case" type="CaseType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  <xs:element name="Lookup" type="LookupType"/>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="If"/>
    <xs:element name="Then"/>
    <xs:element name="Else"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

You will then be able to restrict the content for the XML1 case (provided the content is wrapped in a dedicated element).  **Using `mixed="true"`, it is not possible to restrict the text further using XSD 1.0.**   (Schematron or XSD 1.1's `xs:assert` can layer additional constraints on mixed content -- thanks to @Abel for the reminder.)

Comment: _"Using mixed="true", it is not possible to restrict the text further."_ >> unless with XSD 1.1 and assertions, or Schematron (not sure about RelaxNG), if either of those are an option.

Comment: So I Need to redesign my xslt to get something like: <BusinessRule>
   <Symbol>ABC</Symbol>
</BusinessRule> to be able to restrict the Content? I guess if I do this I dont Need mixed="true" anymore...

Comment: Right, and without `mixed="true"` you'll safeguard against text appearing throughout the `BusinessRule` content:  e.g: `<If>condition1</If>Probably don't want text here<Then>action1</Then>`.